# Android - Event after detecting 'x' number of rolls around local Z axis

Tags: android, android-activity, android-sensors

I'm currently struggling with the use of detectors in Android. I'm working on an app, and I'd like it to perform certain operations after the user make their phone 'roll' in their hand.

To be more precise, I'd like them to roll their phone 720° around the local Z Axis (if I'm not mistaken, the 'height' of the phone) and then, have the app return something.

I really don't know how to do this. So far, the best I've came up with was to declare 8 boolean variables accounting each for a quarter of a roll made, set to true when roll values gets within a certain range. Yeah. I'm that desperate.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could accumulate the change in roll angles, taking into account for when the angle crosses the 2*pi boundary.  Notify the user when the total roll angle is above 4*pi or less than -4*pi.

```
void updateTotalRoll(float currentAngle) {
    if ((currentAngle < (pi/2)) && (prevAngle > (3*pi/2))) {
        totalRoll += (currentAngle+2*pi-prevAngle);
    } else if ((currentAngle > (3*pi/2)) && (prevAngle < (pi/2))) {
        totalRoll -= (prevAngle+2*pi-currentAngle);
    } else {
        totalRoll += currentAngle-prevAngle;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! Great answer. Shouldn't there be a timeout somewhere though?

Comment: Sure, though the implementation would depend upon how you are timing the event.  For example, looking for rolls throughout the lifetime of your application is different then requesting a roll from the user and then timing out if the roll doesn't happen in a certain amount of time.