# Roll around non-geomagnetical axis

Tags: android, android-sensors

Follow up from my previous question : [Android - Event after detecting 'x' number of rolls around local Z axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32907233/android-event-after-detecting-x-number-of-rolls-around-local-z-axis)

What I'd like to do is to trigger an event when a roll is done, around the height-axis of the phone.

Now, thanks to answers, I've managed to understand how I can trigger a post-roll event.

But I still struggle on how to get consistent roll data, since most of the methods I've seen use the geomagnetical axis. Which means that 'roll' is not the same thing when my phone is laying on a table or straight up in my hand.

**I really would like to know, how can I register the same data when I roll my phone around its height-centered axis, whatever the phone orientation is**

Comment: Please give reference to your previous question.

Comment: Here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32907233/android-event-after-detecting-x-number-of-rolls-around-local-z-axis